# Explain the programe : Using 'this()' passing argument in constructor

Tags: java, xcode

```
class B{
A object;
B(A object){this.object = object;}
    void display(){System.out.println(object.data);}}
class A{
    int data = 10;
    A(){
        B b = new B(this);
        b.display();
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Can any one explain this program, Which part execute first and how value transfer.

Comment: The code is not C++, so why is it tagged C++?

Comment: If this question is to make the cut, it will have to be rephrased. Example: what specifically did you expect to happen, why did you think it should. Then ask "why it doesn't". Also code will have to be formatted in an acceptable way. At least that will give us an actual problem statement to answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are doing

```
B b = new B(this);
```

in the class A, that means you are passing as parameter the actual instance of the class A, that is the object **a** that you created here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
}
```